# Connect Android Studio and Wear 3.0 smartwatch via wi-fi

Tags: android-studio, android-wifi, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

ADB debugging needs connection between Android Studio and Wear 3.0 smartwatch (Samsung Galaxy SW 4). How make them work together?

Answer (score 2):

0. Switch ON Developer Mode on your Smartwatch, including A) Activation Developer Mode in Settings (in most cases push many times on Settings-> About watch -> Software -> Software Version) B) Set ON ADB Debugging C) Set ON Wi-Fi Debugging
1. Connect work station with Android Studio and smartwatch wear 3.0 to the same wi-fi network
2. Connect smartwatch via usb charger with workstation (obligatory in most cases at least once)
3. Send the command in Terminal - adb connect XXX.YYY.Z.A:5555, where XXX.YYY.Z.A - address of your Wi-fi - find it in settings of wifi in smartwatch or workstation
4. Accept the request on the smartwatch (always allow / always trust);
5. Check in Studio the change from No Device to your smartwatch.

Notes:

1. sometimes it's obligatory to turn on \ off ADB Debugging and Wi-Fi Debugging on smartwatch and try again;
2. sometimes the connection between smartwatch and Studio is working without USB connection at all (but mostly one time and you need to repeat "adb connect XXX.YYY.Z.A:5555";
3. sometimes you need smartphone in the same Wi Fi network with workstation and smartwatch, sometimes it works well without smartphone.